# Gonk droid spinning saw blade

Tags: technic, star-wars, boost

This is the Gonk Droid from set 75253 Boost Droid Commander:
[image: Gonk Droid]

The accessories for the third mission "defending the Falcon" have been added.

The right arm can punch and shoot a "laser beam".

However the left arm can only move the saw blade up and down.

I would like for the blade to spin AND the arm to move up or down.
Is this feasible?

Comment: That saw blade only has a hole for a pin, that makes it hard to transfer a rotating motion to it.

Comment: I think blade rotation can be achieved with some friction based solution: 1) a rubber wheel spinning a blade; 2) using a friction pin for a blade. The main challenge here is to transfer rotating motion to the blade. However it isn't clear if there is enough place to store the motors and connection ports for the motors.

Comment: @Alex, there's an internal motor from the boost move hub. It's not the intention to add an additional motor. It's indeed the intention to rotate the saw by friction.

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve Do you want him to move around with a spinning saw blade, or have it spinning when his arm goes down?

Comment: @Uli, when the arm goes down (in reverse I suppose when the arm goes up). Movement (legs) is by the external motor in this set

Comment: If you are ready to commit such blasphemy, then gluing a small weight on the edge of the blade would result in the blade swinging or even making complete turns when the arm is moved up and down, depending on the acceleration of the arm movement.

Comment: FWIW this was in fact an intentional decision by Lego - they were concerned what some children could create with s spinning blade, especially since some of those motors are capable of quite some speed and torque.

Comment: Hi htmlcoderexe. Interesting remark, would you happen to have a source for that information (a link perhaps) ?